# What am I? (I really enjoy board games.)

Tags: riddle

> I pla(y) chess
>   I am the best
>   I will only m:Ove faster
>   B)ut there is be one skill
>   I can't master:)

Comment: Is it _typing_?

Comment: @dmg no, but it could help you solve the riddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> A computer/machine/AI?

I pla(y) chess

> You can verse 'the computer' in chess

I am the best

> Computers are great (and also better at us than playing chess, among other things)

I will only m:Ove faster

> Computers can, well, compute and process a lot of things faster than us. In the context of chess this could mean they take less time to decide on the next move.

B)ut there is be one skill
I can't master:)

> <strike>This skill could be "being alive" or "being human", in general 'having consciousness'.</strike>  EDIT: After the OP's comment, the skill is the ability to have emotions, as suggested by the *emoti*cons ( (Y), :O, B), :) ) within the riddle.

Comment: You're right! Except that I meant something a bit different with the *emoti*cons.

Comment: @grooveplex Having emotions? :P